# Java scope and life cycle of bean in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security

I have this question, in a spring web application when we declare a bean singleton and inside a bean prototype every time that we invoke a singleton the prototype bean will be same, but if i want a prototype component inside a faacde inside a controller, how last component can be prototype if other are singleton? 
The schema is this singleton controller->singleton facade->prototype service
Thank u.

Comment: Huh??? You may need to clean up some grammar here. It's very tough to follow what you're asking

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly there are many options that you can use. The most popular:

1.**Scoped proxy**. Add this annotation to you prototype bean:

`@Scope(
  value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, 
  proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`

2.**@Lookup annotation** with method injection:

```
@Component
public class SingletonFacade {

   @Lookup
   public PrototypeBean getPrototypeService() {
       return null;
   }
}
```

3.**ObjectFactory Interface**:

```
@Componenet
public class SingletonFacade {

   @Autowired
   private ObjectFactory<PrototypeService> prototypeBeanObjectFactory;

   public PrototypeBean getPrototypeInstance() {
       return prototypeBeanObjectFactory.getObject();
   }
}
```

You can find more information here - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton